# Is it possible to have an array containing both arrays and primitives in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing a project in Java in which I'm looking at the frequency characters occur after each other character in a text.  When I'm collecting my results, I'm storing them in a 2d array of `int`s.  However, in the same results table, I want to store some results about the whole thing.

Is it possible to have an array where some of the elements are arrays, and others are primitives?

Comment: BTW `int[]` is not a primitive, its an Object and it can be in an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have `Object[]` and store a mix a types, although it would have to be the wrapper `Integer` (not the primitive `int`).  (Note: you could "cheat" and save each `int` as a single-element array `int[]`, thus making it an Object, but "don't try this at home")

But even if you could, an array isn't the right approach. Instead, create a class for this.

Try something like this:

```
public class FrequencyAnalysis {
    private int[] frequencies;
    private String info;
    private Date lastRun;
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not working. There can only be objects OR primitives in one array. Anything else is just a workaround.

Comment: (+1) for the first how answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would have to store `Object`s (primitives will autobox to Wrapper classes) and then when you read the entries you would need to `instanceof` the `Object` and then cast it safely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boxed types, i.e. java.lang.Integer (So your array type must be Object[]), but better do make a new class for results Storage